# Display data into text box from json in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I want to display data into text box from JSON using SAPUI5.

```
// JSON sample data
var data = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    birthday: {day:01,month:05,year:1982},
    address:[{city:"Heidelberg"}],
    enabled: true
};

// create JSON model instance
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
// set the data for the model
oModel.setData(data);
// set the model to the core
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

// create your controls        
var oTextView = new sap.ui.commons.TextView("textView", {
    // bind text property of textview to firstName property in the model
    text: "{/firstName}",
    tooltip: "First Name"
});
var oTxt = new sap.ui.commons.TextField("txtField", {
    // bind text property of textfield to firstName property in the model
    value: "{/firstName}"
});
```

Above code is working but I when I transfer the json data in JSON file and tried to load on this scenario data are not loaded.

Right Now my Json file look like :

```
{
  "UserDetails":[
{
  "userid": "Test-Id", 
  "sapname": "Test-SAP-Form", 
  "age": 37, 
  "annualleave": 32
}
]}
```

When transfer Json data in Json file then I used below code to load data :

```
var userDetailsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
userDetailsModel.loadData("json/UserDetails.json");
userDetailsModel.setData("json/UserDetails.json");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(userDetailsModel, "UserDetails");
```

But I am unable to display data into TextBox.

What is my mistake?

Comment: You don't need to use `setData` if you do `loadData` first; `setData`expects an object/array, whereas `loadData` already stores the object/array in the json file into the model

Comment: I have tried with that. Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (simple) syntax for databinding is `{model>path}`, so when you do `setModel(model, "modelname")` you need to do `{modelname>path}`.

In your case the required value is

```
var oTxt = new sap.ui.commons.TextField("txtField", {
    // bind text property of textfield to firstName property in the model
    value: "{UserDetails>/firstName}"
});
```

And remove the line with `model.setData`, as Qualiture mentioned in his comment

Edit: Your JSON-file is different to the path you are passing to the Controls. With that structure you need to set the path to `{UserDetails>/UserDetails/0/firstName}`

Comment: I followed your instruction but still its not working.

Comment: Ok your json file looks different to what I expected.

Comment: Do you have any example for save data into json using SAPUI5?

Comment: Good to hear that it works. I don't know about saving data directly with UI5, I only use it together with an Apache Tomcat so the Java servlets can do stuff like that.

Comment: Can you give me an some example how it works with servlet for saving data in json?

Comment: You create a Servlet that accepts JSON-data and simply writes the data into a file with a FileOutputStream or else; It would be the best if you google creating a tomcat servlet since i am no expert in this.

Comment: Can you help me for another issue? Now I try to do the bind data into dropdown box by same json file format. How to do that?